# Caching images for Unity WebGL - without Unsafe site warning

Tags: unity-game-engine, unity-webgl

How do you cache images properly for a Unity WebGL site, without the Unsafe site warning popping up? (Currently, images are cached using System.IO.File... in Unity C#)

https://support.google.com/chrome/answer/99020?p=unauthenticated&visit_id=636777539543934908-214567623&rd=1#content